# Arduino program does not work with Proteus

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I wrote an Arduino program for the simulation in Proteus. I have an Arduino mega 2560 board and 7-segment cathode. I want the 7-segment to show number "8". I already compiled Arduino program and copied the path of .hex file to put on the board. When I run the simulation, the 7-segment does not light up; however, the simulation was running with no errors. I am very new to this. help me please.

[Proteus, Arduino mega 2560, 7-segment cathode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbV7F.png)

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(0, 1);
  digitalWrite(1, 1);
  digitalWrite(2, 1);
  digitalWrite(3, 1);
  digitalWrite(4, 1);
  digitalWrite(5, 1);
  digitalWrite(6, 1);
}
```

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.  Post code.  Re-read how to use the site.

Comment: Maybe some emulating problems? Not all the things in proteus will work well, especially the transistor emulation (I myself sometimes face this!).

Comment: Could you check if other pins work? Or check if that Arduino 2560 simulation board work?

Comment: @raspiduino everything on the board works fine.

Comment: can you upload the schematics file anywhere and post to this?

Comment: @raspiduino here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JiHuctUAi6PV6ahW22rAyP2ex_eYxaTH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine worked very well, have you chosen the Atmega2560 processor in Arduino IDE?
[image: Arduino IDE]

This is the picture of a working schematic:
[image: Proteus]

Why isn't it working on your device?

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much for your help. The problem is I did not choose the correct board in Arduino IDE. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are Cambodian, right? I feel sorry for your country's Covid 19 problems =((

Comment: Yes, it's pretty bad here. Thank you so much tho.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check on proteus pins indicators to see if there is any power or flushing on them. Its a quick to troubleshoot and see if your `digitalWrite()` functions are indeed writing to those pins

Comment: I already checked. The pins indicators show no errors and the digitalWrite() functions are correctly refer to those pins.